# How do you derive the secant method formula from the equation below?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

The Secant Method forumula is;

$$ x_{i+1}=x_i - \frac{f(x_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})}{f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})}.$$

Derive the formula from the equation below;

$$\frac{f(x_i)}{f(x_{i-1})}=\frac{x_i-x_{i+1}}{x_{i-1}-x_{i+1}}.$$

Comment: What have you tried? Basically all you have to do is manipulate the equation so as to get it into the form you need. Start by getting the fraction alone on one side.

Comment: @rogerl I've multiplied the top of the L.F.S by the bottom of the R.H.S and equaled it to the top of the R.H.S multiplied by the bottom of the L.H.S but i do not know where to go from there. Could you start me off in the right direction please?

Comment: Once you have solved for $x_{i+1}$, it may be useful to bring the right-hand side of the **first** equation in the OP to a common denominator, observe the cancellation of the $x_if(x_i)$ terms, and conclude the equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ x_{i+1}=x_i - \frac{f(x_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})}{f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})} \\ \overset{(1)}\iff \frac{f(x_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})}{f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})}=x_i -x_{i+1} \\ \overset{(2)}\iff  f(x_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})=(x_i -x_{i+1})(f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})) = (x_i -x_{i+1})f(x_i)- (x_i -x_{i+1})f(x_{i-1}) \\ 
\overset{(3)}\iff f(x_i)(x_{i+1}-x_{i-1})=f(x_i)(x_i-x_{i-1}-x_i+x_{i+1})=-(x_i -x_{i+1})f(x_{i-1}) \\ 
\overset{(4)}\iff \frac{f(x_i)}{f(x_{i-1})}=\frac{x_{i}-x_{i+1}}{x_{i-1}-x_{i+1}}
$$

(1) subtract $x_i$ on both sides

(2) multiply both sides by $(f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1}))$

(3) subtract $f(x_i)(x_i-x_{i+1})$ on both sides

(4) divide both sides by $-(x_{i+1}-x_{i-1})f(x_{i-1})$, note that if $(x_{i+1}-x_{i-1}) = 0$ or $f(x_{i-1})=0$ then the original problem makes no sense so we may suppose that they are different from $0$.